# References in my .bib file show several errors

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I have the following code in my `bibliography.bib` archive;

```
@article{suarez47,
  title={Mastering chaos in ecology},
  author={Suarez, Inti},
  journal={Ecological Modelling},
  volume={117},
  number={2},
  pages={305--314},
  year={1999},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@book{volterra50,
  title={Variazioni e fluttuazioni del numero d'individui in specie animali conviventi},
  author={Volterra, Vito}
  publisher = {In Italian}
}
@article{hopfbiff52,
 author={Zhou, Ming-Chun and Liu, Zong Yu},
 title={Hopf bifurcations in a Ricardo Malthus model.}
 issn={0096-3003},
 Journal={Applied Mathematics and Computation}, 
 number=6,
 volume=21,
 pages={2425-2432},
 year=2010
}


@article{mandalorder35,
 Author = {Mandal, Sandip and Ray, Santanu and Roy, Samar and JA[cedilla]rgensen, Sven Erik},
 title={Order to chaos and vice versa in an aquatic ecosystem.},
 ISSN={0304-3800},
 journal={Ecological Modelling}, 
 number={3-4},
 volume={197}
 pages={498},
  Year={2006},
}
@article{alessandrononlineal15,
 author={D.Alessandro, Simone},
 ISSN={0921-8009},
 journal={Ecological Economics}, 
 number={3-4},
 volume={62}
 pages={473},
 title={Non-linear dynamics of population and natural resources: The emergence of different patterns of development},
 year={2007}
}
@article{sorek46,
 author={SOREK, Gilad, Berglas School of Economics},
 title={Tel Aviv University}
 journal={Thesis}
 year={2006}
}
```

When I compile my `.tex` the following errors appear;

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX)
The top-level auxiliary file: PropuestaInvestigacion.aux
The style file: abbrv.bst
Database file #1: biblio.bib
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 137 of file biblio.bib
 :  
 :  author = {A. Dhooge, W. Govaerts, Yu.A. Kuznetsov, W. Mestrom, A.M. Riet and  B.Sautois}
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 233 of file biblio.bib
 :  
 :  pages={498},
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 251 of file biblio.bib
 :  
 :  pages={473},
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 265 of file biblio.bib
 :  
 :  journal={Thesis}
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 297 of file biblio.bib
 :   
 :   publisher = {In Italian}
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 307 of file biblio.bib
 :  
 :  issn={0096-3003},
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Warning--empty title in alessandrononlineal15
Warning--empty year in alessandrononlineal15
Warning--empty year in mandalorder35
Warning--empty journal in sorek46
Warning--empty year in sorek46
Warning--empty publisher in volterra50
Warning--empty year in volterra50
Warning--empty journal in hopfbiff52
Warning--empty year in hopfbiff52
(There were 6 error messages)
```

How can I fix the errors?

Comment: Check the separating commas, there are some missing. Btw, the file that you are showing is not the file that generated the errors. But basically you can find the errors yourself, the messages are self-explanatory (giving line numbers and context lines).

Comment: The first error in the `blg` seems to relate to an entry where `author = {A. Dhooge, W. Govaerts, Yu.A. Kuznetsov, W. Mestrom, A.M. Riet and  B.Sautois}` which is not included in the question, can you post that entry from the `bib` file (it can  be found around line 137 of the `biblio.bib` file).  If you could provide a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that reproduces your error it will be easier to spot what is going wrong (you may spot the issue yourself in the process of preparing such!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have missing commas in your shown bib entrys.  I created a MWE using the package `filecontents` to concatenate a valid TeX code and a valid bib file together to create a correctly compiling MWE.

With the following code

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
@article{suarez47,
  title={Mastering chaos in ecology},
  author={Suarez, Inti},
  journal={Ecological Modelling},
  volume={117},
  number={2},
  pages={305--314},
  year={1999},
  publisher={Elsevier},
}
@book{volterra50,
  title={Variazioni e fluttuazioni del numero d'individui in specie animali conviventi},
  author={Volterra, Vito},
  publisher = {In Italian},
  year={MISSING},
}
@article{hopfbiff52,
 author={Zhou, Ming-Chun and Liu, Zong Yu},
 title={Hopf bifurcations in a Ricardo Malthus model.},
 issn={0096-3003},
 Journal={Applied Mathematics and Computation}, 
 number=6,
 volume=21,
 pages={2425-2432},
 year=2010,
}
@article{mandalorder35,
 Author = {Mandal, Sandip and Ray, Santanu and Roy, Samar and JA[cedilla]rgensen, Sven Erik},
 title={Order to chaos and vice versa in an aquatic ecosystem.},
 ISSN={0304-3800},
 journal={Ecological Modelling}, 
 number={3-4},
 volume={197},
 pages={498},
  Year={2006},
}
@article{alessandrononlineal15,
 author={D.Alessandro, Simone},
 ISSN={0921-8009},
 journal={Ecological Economics}, 
 number={3-4},
 volume={62},
 pages={473},
 title={Non-linear dynamics of population and natural resources: The emergence of different patterns of development},
 year={2007},
}
@article{sorek46,
 author={SOREK, Gilad, Berglas School of Economics},
 title={Tel Aviv University},
 journal={Thesis},
 year={2006},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{showframe}  % to visualise the typing area and margins
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

This is text with \cite{Goossens} and \cite{adams}.

\nocite{*} % to test all bib entrys
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

you get the following resulting pdf file:

[image]

BTW: I added a `MISSING` to the missing year entry for your `Volterra` bib entry.  You will need to change this yourself.  This should be done in your bib entrys not shown to us ...

Comment: I have to add a year to Volterra even if it is a book? becouse I have other references that do not have year and do not have problems when compiling.

Comment: @JuanMuñoz - When using the `unsrt` bibliography style, the `year` field is *required* for entries of type `@book`. (The year field is not required for entries of type `@misc`.)

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be missing some commas/`{}` in your bibtex file.  The below code will fix most of your problems, however, things like missing years are beyond me, you'll need to add those yourself;

```
@article{suarez47,
title={Mastering chaos in ecology},
author={Suarez, Inti},
journal={Ecological Modelling},
volume={117},
number={2},
pages={305--314},
year={1999},
publisher={Elsevier}
}
@book{volterra50,
title={Variazioni e fluttuazioni del numero d'individui in specie animali conviventi},
author={Volterra, Vito},
publisher = {In Italian}
}
@article{hopfbiff52,
author={Zhou, Ming-Chun and Liu, Zong Yu},
title={Hopf bifurcations in a Ricardo Malthus model.},
issn={0096-3003},
Journal={Applied Mathematics and Computation},
number={6},
volume={21},
pages={2425-2432},
year={2010}
}


@article{mandalorder35,
Author = {Mandal, Sandip and Ray, Santanu and Roy, Samar and JA[cedilla]rgensen, Sven Erik},
title={Order to chaos and vice versa in an aquatic ecosystem.},
ISSN={0304-3800},
journal={Ecological Modelling},
number={3-4},
volume={197},
pages={498},
Year={2006}
}
@article{alessandrononlineal15,
author={D.Alessandro, Simone},
ISSN={0921-8009},
journal={Ecological Economics},
number={3-4},
volume={62},
pages={473},
title={Non-linear dynamics of population and natural resources: The emergence of different patterns of development},
year={2007}
}
@article{sorek46,
author={SOREK, Gilad, Berglas School of Economics},
title={Tel Aviv University},
journal={Thesis},
year={2006}
}
```